# Plot in subplot matplotlib with custom (external) function

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a similar question to what has been answered before ([matplotlib: make plots in functions and then add each to a single subplot figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48129222/matplotlib-make-plots-in-functions-and-then-add-each-to-a-single-subplot-figure)). However, I want to have more advanced plots. I'm using this function for plotting (taken from https://towardsdatascience.com/an-introduction-to-bayesian-inference-in-pystan-c27078e58d53):

```
def plot_trace(param, param_name='parameter', ax=None, **kwargs):
  """Plot the trace and posterior of a parameter."""

  # Summary statistics
    mean = np.mean(param)
    median = np.median(param)
    cred_min, cred_max = np.percentile(param, 2.5), np.percentile(param, 97.5)

  # Plotting
    #ax = ax or plt.gca()
    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.plot(param)
    plt.xlabel('samples')
    plt.ylabel(param_name)
    plt.axhline(mean, color='r', lw=2, linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(median, color='c', lw=2, linestyle='--')
    plt.axhline(cred_min, linestyle=':', color='k', alpha=0.2)
    plt.axhline(cred_max, linestyle=':', color='k', alpha=0.2)
    plt.title('Trace and Posterior Distribution for {}'.format(param_name))

    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.hist(param, 30, density=True); sns.kdeplot(param, shade=True)
    plt.xlabel(param_name)
    plt.ylabel('density')
    plt.axvline(mean, color='r', lw=2, linestyle='--',label='mean')
    plt.axvline(median, color='c', lw=2, linestyle='--',label='median')
    plt.axvline(cred_min, linestyle=':', color='k', alpha=0.2, label='95% CI')
    plt.axvline(cred_max, linestyle=':', color='k', alpha=0.2)

    plt.gcf().tight_layout()
    plt.legend()
```

and I would like to have those two subplots for different parameters. If I use this code, it simply overwrites the plot and ignores the ax parameter. Would you please help me how to make it work also for more than just 2 parameters?

```
params = [mu_a,mu_tau]
param_names = ['A mean','tau mean']

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(16,16))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
fig.suptitle('Convergence and distribution of parameters')

plot_trace(params[0], param_name=param_names[0], ax = ax1)
plot_trace(params[1], param_name=param_names[1], ax = ax2)
```

The expected result would be to have those plots next to each other
[How one subplot should look like (what the function makes)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ9ve.png). Thank you.

Comment: You have to plot with `ax1.plot` / `ax2.plot` like in this exapmle: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html

Comment: Yes, your function needs to take in **two** axes and specifically plot to those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by both @Sebastian-R and @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, the problem is that you are creating the subplots inside the functions instead of using what is passed to the `ax=` keyword. In addition, if you want to plot on two different subplots, you need to pass two axes instances to your function

There are two ways to correct the problem:

- the first solution would be to re-write your function to use [the object-oriented API](https://matplotlib.org/api/api_overview.html) of matplotlib (this is the solution that I recommend, although it requires more work)

code:

```
def plot_trace(param, axs, param_name='parameter', **kwargs):
    """Plot the trace and posterior of a parameter."""
    # Summary statistics
    (...)
    # Plotting
    ax1 = axs[0]
    ax1.plot(param)
    ax1.set_xlabel('samples')  # notice the difference in notation here
    (...)

    ax2 = axs[1]
    ax2.hist(...); sns.kdeplot(..., ax=ax2)
    (...)
```

- the second solution keeps your current code, with the exception that, since the `plt.xxx()` functions work on the current axes, you need to make the axes that you passed as an argument the current axes:

code:

```
def plot_trace(param, axs, param_name='parameter', **kwargs):
    """Plot the trace and posterior of a parameter."""
    # Summary statistics
    (...)
    # Plotting
    plt.sca(axs[0])
    plt.plot(param)
    plt.xlabel('samples')
    (...)

    plt.sca(axs[1])
    plt.hist(...)
    (...)
```

Then you need to create the number of subplots that you need at the end (so if you want to plot two parameters, you'll have to create 4 subplots) and call your function as you had wanted:

```
params = [mu_a,mu_tau]
param_names = ['A mean','tau mean']

fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(16,16))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
fig.suptitle('Convergence and distribution of parameters')

plot_trace(params[0], axs=[ax1, ax3], param_name=param_names[0])
plot_trace(params[1], axs=[ax2, ax4], param_name=param_names[1])
```

Comment: You may want to reread the question, and my comment below it.

Comment: I see, i missed the part where there were two subplots generated by the function

Comment: Thank you all very much for comments and @Diziet Asahi for solutions, both work.