# Adding existing AxesSubplot to grid

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization, subplot

If I have a function (get_plot()) from a library which plots and returns an object of type "matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot". How can I generate 4 of these plots and add them to a matplotlib subplot grid?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1,2,3,4,5]})

def get_plot(data):
    return df.plot(data)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)

axes[0][0].plt(get_plot(df))
axes[0][1].plt(get_plot(df))
axes[1][0].plt(get_plot(df))
axes[1][1].plt(get_plot(df))
```

throws an error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'plt'
```

**Note:** the function get_plot() comes from a library which I do not want to modify.

Comment: Hi, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48129456/11246056

Comment: Thank you Laurent. That was exactly what I was looking for. Hopefully, someone else who needs this finds it. I have already found a walk around and have submitted the work.